# Google app script data coming back as undefined

Tags: jquery, html, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to submit data from a web page to a Google spreadsheet, I copied the code from a tutorial online and tweaked it according to my needs. The original code if for two inputs and one submit button, I tried changing it around so I should be able to have two submit buttons and each button will submit just one input data.

The issue I have am struggling with is that I can't make one input data show up without the other one either saying undefined or not showing up at all. I also want both inputs to show up on the same row next to each other.

In example: I want 'clock in' - which is my first button to appear in row 1 column 1, and 'clock out' to appear on row 1 column 1. Take in consideration that these buttons will not be submitted at the same time.

I strongly believe this code is a mess but I have deleted and tweaked so much already that I don't know what to do anymore .

My first code is the code.gs, which is in my google app script.

I will highly appreciate any help, this thing is driving me crazy already.

please note this is my first time posting a question so if I went wrong somewhere you can let me know.

Thank you

```js
function doGet(e){
  
  var op = e.parameter.action;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("My spreadsheet url goes here");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("input-test");


  if(op=="insert")
    return insert_value(e,sheet);

  
 if(op=="insert")
    return insert_value2(e,sheet);
 }


function insert_value(request,sheet){
 
 var id = request.parameter.id;
 var name = request.parameter.name;

  

  var flag=1;
  var lr= sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var id1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if(id1==id){
      flag=0;
  var result="Id already exist..";
    } }
  //add new row with recieved parameter from client
  if(flag==1){
  var d = new Date();
   var currentTime = d.toLocaleString();
  var rowData = sheet.appendRow([id,name]);//if I take off name id won't work at all
  var result="Insertion successful";
  }
     result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  
    
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   
  }

function insert_value2(){

  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var name= request.parameter.name;

  var rowData = sheet.appendRow([id,name]); //if i take off id name won't work at all
     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
  var script_url = "i have my google sheet link here";
  
  function insert_value() {
 
    var id1 = $("#id").val();
 
    var url = script_url+"?callback=ctrlq&id="+id1+"&action=insert";
 
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
 
  }
 
  function insert_value2() {
 
  var name = $("#name").val();
  
    var url = script_url+"?callback=ctrlq&name="+name+"&action=insert";
 
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
     method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
 
  }
 
  function ctrlq(e) {
 
}
 
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
 
  <div class="time-inputs clock-in text-center">
     <h4>Clock In Time</h4>
        <input name="Clock-In" type="time" id="id">
       <input class="enter-time-btn btn btn-secondary shadow-none" type="submit" value="Enter Time" id ="clockInBtn" onClick="insert_value()">
  </div>
  </form>
  
  <br>
  
  <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  
  <div class="time-inputs clock-out text-center">
        <h4>Clock Out Time</h4>
        <input  name="Clock-Out" type="time" id="name">
        <input class="enter-time-btn btn btn-secondary shadow-none" type="submit" value="Enter Time" id ="clockOutBtn" onClick="insert_value2()">
  </div>
  </form>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From What I see, the following code snippet from your Code.gs will never be called.

```
if(op=="insert")
 return insert_value2(e,sheet);
```

Because the first if statement is also true and the execution returns from there.

I would suggest below changes and see if the fix anything.

In your HTML file:

```
function insert_value() { 
 var id1 = $("#id").val();
 var url = script_url+"?callback=ctrlq&id="+id1+"&action=insert_checkIn";
```

Similarly

```
function insert_value2() {
 var name = $("#name").val();
 var url = script_url+"?callback=ctrlq&name="+name+"&action=insert_checkOut";
```

And inside your Code.gs

```
if(op == "insert_checkIn")
  return insert_value(e,sheet);
if(op=="insert_checkOut")
  return insert_value2(e,sheet);
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Thank you for your time try to help me, I tried changing whatever you suggested, however now, when I enter check-in check-out shows up as undefined and when trying to enter check out it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not clear if your server side functions called at all or not! Did the server side functions invoked with your previous code? Also consider invoking the server side functions directly using the google.script.run. You can find documentation here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: I am sorry but I a m not clear what you a referring to, the code I posted is all the code I have for this